# Using nginx proxy to serve static S3 to a different bucket for bots like googlebot

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, googlebot

Using nginx to proxy subdomains of superduper.io to a specific folder in S3 bucket. The bucket has a folder for each subdomain that holds a static HTML website.

Now I want to redirect bots to a different S3 bucket. What do I need to add to my nginx.conf file?

```
worker_processes auto;
# include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.superduper.io;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/superduper.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/superduper.error.log;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            set $bucket "https://superduper-spa.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443";
            rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

            # matches: subdomain.superduper.io
            if ($host ~ ^([^.]*)\.superduper\.io) {
                set $subdomain $1;
                proxy_pass https://$bucket/${subdomain}${uri};
            }

            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $bucket;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
        }
    }

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Just wondering. Shouldn't bucket `set $bucket "superduper-spa.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"`?. Your final Url is forming as `https://https://superduper-spa.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443` right?

Comment: you cant use port 443 SSL with a bucket, you'll need to stick cloudfront in front of it if you require SSL encryption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nginx doesn't support an `else` statement, nor an `if` with more than a single condition, it may get tricky to write certain configurations that depend on multiple variables.

For your usecase, there are two improvements for a potential solution, which can be used either together or apart:

- You might want to convert your existing `if` with a regex around `$host` into a *named capture* within `server_name` as per http://nginx.org/r/server_name.  This way, you'll then be free to use whatever transformation you require around `$http_user_agent` matching against the bots, e.g., by using an `if` statement more like an actual conditional than just as a way to capture the subdomain.

  ```
  -server_name *.example.su;
  -if ($host ~ ^([^.]*)\.example\.su$) {
  -       set $subdomain $1
  -}
  +server_name ~^(p<subdomain>[^.]*)\.example\.su$;
  ```
- You might want to make use of http://nginx.org/r/map.  It allows to map any inputs to an output.  You can combine a match for both `$host` and `$http_user_agent` to make the transformation.

  ```
  map $http_host/$http_user_agent $bucket {
      "~^(p<subdomain>[^.]*)\.example\.su.*bot.*$"    $bucketPrefix/$subdomain/bot;
      "~^(p<subdomain>[^.]*)\.example\.su.*$" $bucketPrefix/$subdomain;
      default             $bucketPrefix;
  }
  server {
      …
          proxy_pass $bucket$uri;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution would be to use Cloudfront in front of S3, then use a Lamdbda at edge function to redirect specific user-agents to a different bucket without having to touch nginx.